# OutputText só atualiza após Restart do Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, tomcat

Estou utilizando Tomcat 7, Eclipse Juno (no Windows 7) e Primefaces 5 para minha aplicação.

Após realizar o cadastro de algumas informações na base de dados (vacinas para caderneta de vacinação), acesso uma tela (vacina-caderneta.xhtml) para visualizar o status por paciente do meu sistema.

O fato é que quando o dataGrid do Primefaces é carregado, o mesmo não apresenta as informações da mesma forma que estão dispostas no Banco de Dados (MySQL / JPA-EclipseLink). Mais especificadamente o campo "dtPrevistaAplicacao".

E o mais curioso é que após um RESTART do Tomcat 7, os valores desta campo são apresentados corretamente.

**vacina-caderneta.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Caderneta de Vacinação - UBS+ Web</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="ubs.css" />
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/cabecalho.xhtml" />
    <p:panel header="Caderneta de Vacinação">
        <h:form id="frmCaderneta">
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel for="pacienteNome" value="Nome do Paciente: " />
            <p:inputText id="pacienteNome" size="50"
                value="#{vacinacaoBean.paciente.pessoa.nome}" readonly="TRUE" />
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="Visualizar"
                onclick="PF('dlgPesqPaciente').show()">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:spacer width="25" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Visualizar/Atualizar Caderneta"
                action="#{vacinacaoBean.visualizaCaderneta}" update="vacina" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- DataGrid Vacinação -->
            <p:dataGrid id="vacina" columns="6" var="vacinas" paginator="TRUE"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,18"
                value="#{vacinacaoBean.cadernetaVacinacao}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Vacinas do Paciente
                </f:facet>
                <p:panel>
                    <p:panelGrid id="vacinaDose" columns="2">

                        <h:outputText value="Vacina: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{vacinas.vacina.nome}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Data Prevista: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{vacinas.dtPrevistaAplicacao}" >
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                        </h:outputText>

                        <h:outputText value="Dose: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{vacinas.numDose}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Status: " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="status" value="#{vacinas.status}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Concluído" itemValue="Concluído" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Pendente" itemValue="Pendente" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>


                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:dataGrid>

        </h:form>
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/rodape.xhtml" />
    </p:panel>

    <!-- @Fellipe: Dialog de pesquisa do paciente -->
    <p:dialog id="dlgPesqPaciente" widgetVar="dlgPesqPaciente" width="700"
        header="Selecionar o Paciente" modal="TRUE" resizable="FALSE"
        draggable="FALSE">
        <h:form id="frmPesqPaciente">

            <!-- Campo de Pesquisa -->
            <p:outputLabel for="idnome" value="Pesquisar por Nome: " />
            <p:inputText maxlenght="50" size="50" id="idnome" required="FALSE"
                value="#{vacinacaoBean.nome}">
                <p:ajax event="keyup"
                    listener="#{vacinacaoBean.findPacientePorNome}"
                    update="resultadoBusca" />
            </p:inputText>
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Tabela de Pessoas -->
            <p:dataTable id="resultadoBusca"
                value="#{vacinacaoBean.listaPaciente}" var="paciente"
                selection="#{vacinacaoBean.paciente}" selectionMode="single"
                rowKey="#{paciente.id}">

                <p:column headerText="Nome" style="width:400px;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{paciente.pessoa.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Bairro" style="width:100px;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{paciente.pessoa.bairro}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Código SUS"
                    style="width:100px;text-align: center">
                    <h:outputText value="#{paciente.cns}" />
                </p:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Selecionar" update=":frmCaderneta"
                        onclick="PF('dlgPesqPaciente').close();"
                        action="#{vacinacaoBean.findPacientePorNome}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**VacinacaoBean.java**

```
package br.com.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import br.com.modelo.Paciente;
import br.com.modelo.Vacinacao;
import br.com.servico.VacinacaoServico;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class VacinacaoBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Vacinacao vacinacao;
    private Paciente paciente;
    private String nome;
    private List<Vacinacao> cadernetaVacinacao;
    private List<Paciente> listaPaciente;

    public VacinacaoBean() {
        vacinacao = new Vacinacao();
        paciente = new Paciente();
        cadernetaVacinacao = new ArrayList<Vacinacao>();
        listaPaciente = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    public Vacinacao getVacinacao() {
        return vacinacao;
    }

    public void setVacinacao(Vacinacao vacinacao) {
        this.vacinacao = vacinacao;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public List<Paciente> getListaPaciente() {
        return listaPaciente;
    }

    public void setListaPaciente(List<Paciente> listaPaciente) {
        this.listaPaciente = listaPaciente;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Vacinacao> getCadernetaVacinacao() {
        return cadernetaVacinacao;
    }

    public void setCadernetaVacinacao(List<Vacinacao> cadernetaVacinacao) {
        this.cadernetaVacinacao = cadernetaVacinacao;
    }

    // Métodos do Bean

    public void findPacientePorNome() {
        if (nome.equals("")) {
            listaPaciente = null;
        } else {
            try {
                listaPaciente = VacinacaoServico.getInstance()
                        .findPacientePorNome(nome);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void visualizaCaderneta() {
        // Puxando dados de vacinação do Paciente
        try {
            cadernetaVacinacao = VacinacaoServico.getInstance()
                    .cadernetaDoPaciente(paciente.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Vacinacao.java**

```
package br.com.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vacinacao.cadernetaDoPaciente", query = "SELECT v FROM Vacinacao v JOIN v.paciente p WHERE p.id = :idpaciente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vacinacao.findPacientePorNome", query = "SELECT c FROM Paciente c JOIN c.pessoa p WHERE p.nome LIKE :nome")
})
public class Vacinacao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int codigo;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String status;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable=true,name="DT_HR_APLICACAO")
    private Date dtHrAplicacao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable=true,name="DT_PREVISTA_APLICACAO")
    private Date dtPrevistaAplicacao;

    @Column(nullable=false,name="NUM_DOSE")
    private int numDose;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(nullable=true,name="PROXIMA_DOSE")
    private Date proximaDose;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ENFERMEIRO")
    private Funcionario enfermeiro;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PACIENTE")
    private Paciente paciente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_VACINA")
    private Vacina vacina;


    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getDtHrAplicacao() {
        return dtHrAplicacao;
    }

    public void setDtHrAplicacao(Date dtHrAplicacao) {
        this.dtHrAplicacao = dtHrAplicacao;
    }

    public int getNumDose() {
        return numDose;
    }

    public void setNumDose(int numDose) {
        this.numDose = numDose;
    }

    public Date getProximaDose() {
        return proximaDose;
    }

    public void setProximaDose(Date proximaDose) {
        this.proximaDose = proximaDose;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public Vacina getVacina() {
        return vacina;
    }

    public void setVacina(Vacina vacina) {
        this.vacina = vacina;
    }

    public Funcionario getEnfermeiro() {
        return enfermeiro;
    }

    public void setEnfermeiro(Funcionario enfermeiro) {
        this.enfermeiro = enfermeiro;
    }

    public Date getDtPrevistaAplicacao() {
        return dtPrevistaAplicacao;
    }

    public void setDtPrevistaAplicacao(Date dtPrevistaAplicacao) {
        this.dtPrevistaAplicacao = dtPrevistaAplicacao;
    }    
}
```

Lembrando que é inviável para uma aplicação em Produção um restart do servidor de aplicação toda hora =)

Comment: No banco qual o formato da coluna? Timestamp?

Comment: Poderia colocar tambem a classe `Vacinacao`?

Comment: @GustavoCinque, adicionei a classe. Sim, é TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, não consegui voltar a essa pergunta durante o fim de semana. Me parece que está havendo algum tipo de erro na hora de passar o `TIMESTAMP` da tabela para o objeto `Date dtPrevistaAplicacao`. De acordo com a própria documentação: [_The Timestamp.equals(Object) method never returns true when passed an object that isn't an instance of java.sql.Timestamp, because the nanos component of a date is unknown._](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)... Talvez mudando a tabela de `TIMESTAMP` para `DATE` funcione.

Comment: @GustavoCinque, descobri o problema. Na realidade o problema era na geração dos dados, que acontecia em um outro ManagedBean, onde neste a manipulação das data/hora estavam sendo realizadas utilizando objetos do tipo Date. Orientei a trocarem para Calendar, visto que Date tem funções depreciadas, e o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para o problema.

Identifiquei que na realidade o problema só ocorria quando o atributo `dtPrevistaAplicacao` da classe `Vacinacao.java` estava sendo enviado para o banco com um objeto do tipo `java.util.Date`, durante a manipulação dos dados dentro de um ManagedBean.

Desta forma, no método `GET` que o JSF utiliza para popular o componente renderizado do Primefaces na tela, repete o valor para todas as linhas da `dataTable` ou `dataGrid`.

Utilizando objetos do tipo `Calendar`, que aliás é o mais recomendado, o problema foi resolvido. Utilizar `java.sql.Date` também é uma opção.